# In GSL, why do some functions take a "workspace" argument?

Tags: design-patterns, c, libraries

In certain functions in GSL (GNU Scientific Library), some functions take a "workspace" environment as an argument.  For example, `gsl_poly_dd_taylor` from [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Divided-Difference-Representation-of-Polynomials.html) page.  Why?  Wouldn't it be easier for the function to allocate its own memory, or at least the same difficulty?  I suppose that this allows the caller to specify *where* the function works, but I don't see how it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efficiency. GSL is designed to be both time and memory efficient and it makes more sense to pass around the same workspace than have each and every function allocate and free its own.

Comment: Makes sense.  Hadn't thought about reusing the same workspace.  Thanks!